# How to check for invalid/uninitialized object in c++

Tags: c++, error-handling, initialization

Currently, I've created a simple error handling system to check whether a pointer is valid by checking for nullptr like so:

```
        inline void ErrReport(const char8* fileOfError, int32 lineNumberOfError, const Blz::string c_errMessage)
        {
            ErrorContext::LogContext();
            LOG("  ERROR: %s\n", c_errMessage.c_str());
            LOG("  In %s: %i\n\n", fileOfError, lineNumberOfError);
            exit(0);
        }

        #if(_DEBUG)
            #define ERRASSERT(test, msg) do {if (!(test)) Blz::Err::ErrReport(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg);} while (0)
        #endif
```

I can then call ERRASSERT in my code like so:

```
unsgined char* imageData = LoadImage("PathToImage");
ERRASSERT(imageData, "Image did not load properly");
```

Right now, in order to do something similar with non-pointer objects I have a Check() function to see if an object has been initialized or not:

```
        template<typename T> inline bool Check(boost::outcome::expected<T>& obj)
        {
            if (obj)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

With this code, if I understand how to use outcome::expected correctly, I would then just call the above function within my ERRASSERT and everything should work similiarly

```
boost::outcome::expected<ObjectType> obj = functionReturnsObj(); 
ERRASSERT(Check(obj), "Object not initialized!);
```

My question:

Is there a better way to check if an object is initialized without having to wrap everything in boost::outcome::expected? Are there even many scenarios where an object wouldn't be initialized given C++ automatically initializes objects upon creation? Should I even be worried about this?

Comment: Well `int thing;` isn't initialized... You should just initialize things when you declare them if you want to be safe.

Comment: The null pointer is not the only invalid pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo What do you mean?

Comment: @Jason -- You can have a non-NULL pointer that is invalid.  `int *p = new int; delete p;`  Is `p` valid after the `delete`?  How about an uninitialized pointer?  Usually they are not null.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, right. Thanks Paul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a better way to check if an object is initialized

Don't.

> Are there even many scenarios where an object wouldn't be initialized given C++ automatically initializes objects upon creation?

Yes, and it doesn't (always).

But that's the programmer's responsibility (and you can usually rely on compiler warnings to catch silly mistakes).

> Should I even be worried about this?

No.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to elaborate a bit on `Should I even be worried about this?` in addition to @BoundaryImposition's answer.

An uninitialized C++ object may cause you issues in certain cases. If you have `Foo` and create an instance `f` as below, then `f.a` and `f.b` are not initialized and you should not assume they are `0`.

```
struct Foo { int a; int b; };
Foo f;
```